# Hiding examples expanded to the side

Tags: bug, documentation

When choosing to expand examples to the side:
[image: Expanding to the side]

Then clicking the example title to hide it (on the left):
[image: Clicking an example to hide]

Usually it'll leave a plain `x` on the side:
[image: Hiding examples in split-view mode]

Even worse, if you hide the example in split-view mode, click an example (it returns to split-view mode), then hide it again, it breaks both viewing option buttons. It makes it look like you exited split-view mode by showing the viewing option buttons, but then both buttons to require up to two clicks and end up restoring the split-view.

Comment: Which browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Firefox 47 and Chrome 51 on Windows 10. I added images to the original post to provide steps to reproduce this.